# Is it possible to get the number of matched elements using Detox or Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, detox

I need to get the number of elements in a choice list, to use it later. Is it possible to search elements by type (choice list item type), and then to get the number of matched elements?

I saw the atIndex() Detox function, so maybe there is something related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, but will be possible soon using the [`getAttributes()`](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/DetoxNext/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#getAttributes--ios-only) API.